# Ubuntu: "No such file or directory" pero el archivo si existe

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure, server, ubuntu-server

Trato de acceder a la carpeta /minecraft para poder ejecutar mi servidor pero dice que no existe, el problema es que poniendo ls si aparece que minecraft esta en /home

```
root@VM-server:/home# ls
Susir  minecraft
root@VM-server:/home# /minecraft
bash: /minecraft: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

2 cosas. Para cambiarte de directorio, no solo escribes el directorio... escribes

```
cd el-directorio
```

Lo segundo es que si la ruta comienza con `/`, estás indicando la ruta desde la raíz del `sistema de archivos`. O sea, lo que quieres es:

```
cd /home/minecraft
```

O, si ya estás en `/home`:

```
cd minecraft
```

(sin el `/`).

Y bienvenido a DdP.

Comment: Si minecraft es un programa, tambien puede decide ./minecraft

Comment: Es cierto si fuera el caso de que es un ejecutable _pero_ puse la solución en base a lo primero que pone en la pregunta el OP: `trato de acceder a la carpeta /minecraft`.